# Mirth: Custom ack edge case

Tags: mirth

I think this would be an extreme edge case that I need to accomplish:

1. An ORU comes in from a 3rd party application.
2. An AA ack gets returned to the 3rd party application on the same connection.
3. The ORU gets forwarded on to a 3rd party destination system.
4. The destination system will return a positive or a negative ack to Mirth.
5. I need to return a secondary CA acknowledgement to the original sending 3rd party app on a seperate connection.

   5a) Could be a positive (AA) or negative (AE) ACK.

   5b) The acks are custom, so they must be generated through javascript

   5c) If I am sending a positive (AA) ack back to the original sending system I need to populate one of the MSA fields with a value that was in the original ORU message.

Point 5c makes this difficult because I'm not sure of any way to maintain state between original ORU message and the acknowledgement.  Is there any way to do this in Mirth, or do I need to build something by storing ORU information in a database, and looking it up when generating the ACK?

Comment: I'm not clear from your question: In step 4, is the ack returned from the destination returned over the same LLP connection that the forwarded ORU was sent on?

Comment: Also, is the original 3rd party app from step 1 always the same? Or could the message be originating from a variety of sources?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what data point you need out of the original ORU.  Most of the MSH segment shouldn't change.
You could write the data point you need to a channel map variable in your first destination's transformer, make another destination for the return custom ACK and read the result status of the destination above it, and send your custom ack built the datapoint you mapped.
Does your first system need an AA and the second ack or can you not send a single custom ack after receiving your ack from the next system?